# Importing a time-temperature list into Ansys Fluent for simulation

Tags: ansys, fluent

I am using Ansys Fluent for my simulation.

I have a series of connected U pipes surrounded by a hot block (343K) with an inflow of cold water (298K) which is discharging the block.

I would like to simulate only one U pipe with the block around and run the simulation for 720 seconds. Then use the output temperatures as inlet for the simulation using UDF to simulate the second block and U pipe.

The outputs from the first section are a table of temperature with respect to time. It is an Excel file with two columns. I would like to use the exact values from the table (not an approximated function). How can I import these values into Ansys?